# Discord.js bot appearing to not be working, no errors | Could it be my indentation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been working on this bot for a while, before I made an update which included the 'limitedquests' it perfectly worked. But now, as I updated it, multiple things do not work inside of it and since there are no errors, I am really unsure why.
I will post the code here and explain further.

```
client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
if (msg.content === '!quest'){
  if (talkedRecently.has(msg.author.id)) {
            msg.reply("The Quest can be used again in 6 hours (If you get a Very Hard or above quest and you are below Phase 3, you are allowed to not do that quest)");
    } else {
    if (msg.content === '!quest') {
    const randNumberChosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13 + 1);
        if (randNumberChosen == 1){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 2){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed2] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 3){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed3] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 4){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed4] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 5){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed5] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 6){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed6] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 7){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed7] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 8){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed8] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 9){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed9] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 10){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed10] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 11){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed11] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 12){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed12] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen == 13){
        msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed13] });
        }
        talkedRecently.add(msg.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          talkedRecently.delete(msg.author.id);
        }, 21556900);
    }
}
if (msg.content === '!limitedquest'){
  if (talkedRecently4.has(msg.author.id)) {
            msg.reply("The Limited Quest can be used again in 8 hours");
    } else {
    if (msg.content === '!quest') {
    const randNumberChosen4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
        if (randNumberChosen4 == 1){
        msg.reply({embeds: [limitedQuestEmbed1] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen4 == 2){
        msg.reply({embeds: [limitedQuestEmbed2] });
        }
        talkedRecently4.add(msg.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          talkedRecently4.delete(msg.author.id);
        }, 28800000);
    }
}
}
}
if (msg.content === '!chest'){
  if (talkedRecently2.has(msg.author.id)) {
            msg.reply("The Chest can be used again in 12 hours");
    } else {
    if (msg.content === '!chest') {
    const randNumberChosen2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 1){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest1] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 2){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest1] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 3){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest3] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 4){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest3] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 5){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest2] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 6){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest1] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 7){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest4] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 8){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest5] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 9){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest6] });
        }
        if (randNumberChosen2 == 10){
        msg.reply({embeds: [christmasChest7] });
        }
        talkedRecently2.add(msg.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          talkedRecently2.delete(msg.author.id);
        }, 43200000);
    }
}
if (msg.content === '!chestrarity') {
    msg.reply({embeds: [rarity] });
}
if (msg.content === '!christmas') {
    if (talkedRecently3.has(msg.author.id)) {
            msg.reply("3rd day of Chrismas reward available tomorrow :christmas_tree:");
    } else {
    const randNumberChosen3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 1);
    if(randNumberChosen3 < 14){
    randNumberChosen3 = 15;
    }
    console.log(randNumberChosen3);
    msg.reply("Day 2 Christmas Gift.. you get: " + randNumberChosen3 + " EXP");
    talkedRecently3.add(msg.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          talkedRecently3.delete(msg.author.id);
        }, 86400000);
      }
    }
}
});
```

It's not really that big, just a bunch of if statements because of the random number. I am doing all the commands, since there is only 4 or so commands, in one file. The parts that work are "!quest" and "!chest". But after that, "!chestrarity", "!limitedquest", or "!christmas" just do not work at all. I've tried rewriting it, I've also tried to fix indentation. Nothing seems to fix this and I'm really just confused.

And yes, I did define all the things required, I will show it here seperately

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })

const talkedRecently = new Set();
const talkedRecently2 = new Set();
const talkedRecently3 = new Set();
const talkedRecently4 = new Set();
```

Comment: There are many logic flaws in this code but I think biggest one is that you are nesting command conditions into each other, such as `if (msg.content === '!quest')` inside `if (msg.content === '!limitedquest')` which would cause the latter never to be reached for obvious reasons. It looks like you may have mixed up the brackets in a few places which would explain why so commands are not executed (if they are inside other command conditionals).

Comment: In a real production environment I recommend not to store such long timeouts in RAM. Everytime your server restarts, this information is lost. Make a small database where you store the user's discord tag and a timestamp, then query this database every 10 seconds or so to check if a users timestamp is more than X hours before "now" and delete this user's entry from the database. In your command, check if the user is in the database or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your goals:

1. Check the command.
2. Check if the author has already tried the command.
3. If they have, send them a message.
4. If they haven't, generate a random number and send a message depending on the value.

---

You can check the command using either `msg.content == "!command"`, or with `msg.content.startsWith("!command")`.

We then call the handler function for each command. This makes it easier to manage our code.

```
if(msg.command.startsWith("!quest")) questHandler(msg, questCache);
if(msg.command.startsWith("!chest")) chestHandler(msg, chestCache);
if(msg.command.startsWith("!christmas")) christmasHandler(msg, christmasCache);
```

---

Now in the handler we have the logic for the command. I added the cache as the second parameter, so this function won't break if something happens with the cache, such as you changing the variable name.

The rest is your previous code, but cleaned up.

```
function questHandler(msg, cache){
  // check if the author has already done the task.
  if(cache.has(msg.author.id)){
    msg.send("You have to wait 6 hours to do the quest again.")
  } else {
    const num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13);
    num === 1 
      ? msg.reply({embeds: [questEmbed] });
      : msg.reply({embeds: [[`questEmbed${num}`]] });

    cache.add(msg.author.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      cache.delete(msg.author.id);
    }, 60 * 60 * 24 * 6);
  }
}
```

Do the same for the other commands, and it should be a lot easier to manage your code.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not about indentations but braces. You have, for example `if (msg.content === '!limitedquest')` under `if (msg.content === '!quest')`, that is, they should *both* be simultaneously true, which doesn’t really make sense.

So, to fix this, rework through all the blocks and make sure they form a logical and coherent structure. A decent text editor is a great help.

Remember, while JavaScript doesn’t as a language depend on indentations, they are very important for anybody who reads the code. That’s why it’s important to ensure that indentations and blocks (marked by parentheses and brackets and braces) agree.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. When tidying up the entire program, I still have not noticed anything major like the quest part, which I understood because I had the if() limitedquest statement in the if() quest statement. Could it be because I am formatting these if statements incorrectly, such as putting the "}" scrambled all the way at the bottom?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nJMF1UJ8 This is the code you posted with more clear formatting. Hope it helps to see the issue.

Comment: @guptavir Formatting is kind of irrelevant. You could write the complete code in one line and it still will work. Formatting only helps to read it easier.